# Android Emulator removed by Visual Studio 2017 15.5.6

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I was developing a Xamarin Android app, and happily using the Android emulator to test. My environment included Android Emulator Manager (AVD), Android SDK Manager, Android device monitor (DDMS) and more. After having worsening build problems and inexplicable build error messages, I decided to finally update Visual Studio to version 15.5.6 (The last time I had updated was late last year).

After updating, my Xamarin application is not even recognized as a Xamarin application any more, and my environment seems to have been severely corrupted. All the buttons to launch the Android tools are disabled. If I select them from the start menu, or run the EXE (AVD Manager.exe) directly from the file system, it says that tools\android.bat is not found. If I try to debug the application, I get the following output:

```
1>Starting deploy AVD_for_Nexus_6_by_Google ...
1>Starting emulator AVD_for_Nexus_6_by_Google ...
1>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
1>This property is not valid when the SDK is not installed
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why and how did a Visual Studio update screw up my environment so badly, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened Visual Studio Installer (from the Start menu) and selected the Repair command from the "More" dropdown. That fixed it.